# How import multiple notebooks into a new notebook using %run command

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

Can anyone suggest the syntax to import multiple notebooks using %run command in Databricks?

Right now, am importing through seperate run commands for every notebook like below:
%run ./Notebook1
%run ./Notebook2
%run ./Notebook3

I would like to know the syntax to do the import of all the notebooks in single run command

Answer (score 0):

> No, this is not supported right now - each `%run` command needs to be executed separately.

P.S. If you have Databricks code in the [Databricks Repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/) and you're using Python as programming language (or R), then you may switch to use Python modules to modularize code by using [Files in Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/files/workspace-modules) functionality.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/tree/master/unit-tests) of using both methods (`%run` and files in repos) to modularize Python code